# Apollo Core weapons

Tags: alien-isolation

So, I've entered the Apollo Core area and had my weapons taken away.

Is there any way to get them back or do I have to find them again elsewhere in the station?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep playing the story. I can't really say any more without spoiling stuff, but there's no way to progress without giving up your weapons and entering this major stealth section.

> The next section is a stealth area around EMP shielded working joes where you have to sneak. Keep playing until you find a new gun that can take them down, but is also difficult to use effectively (there's a spin up and only head shots work). Shortly after that and before entering the most terrifying level in the game you'll start finding guns again, though everything but the flamethrower is useless by that point.

Comment: I've exited Apollo Core at the bottom without finding a new weapon... is it in there somewhere and I just missed it?  Or is it in the next section after that?

Comment: @powerlord keep going. I don't want to ruin it for you.

Comment: Well, I already found ammo for at least one gun I don't have yet behind a plasma torch door in San Cristobal (yay backtracking!) so that's probably the one I haven't gotten yet.  I try to grab all the items in the rooms I visit by watching the map, so I probably didn't miss the new weapon... oh well, still at work so I'll find out tonight.

Comment: @powerlord You can't really miss it, it's next to a terminal you must use to progress.

Comment: I never got a chance to play last night.  Not sure if I will tonight either as I have some other things I need to take care of after work.

Comment: Finally had a chance to continue on with the game on Saturday, but forgot to come back and mark this as correct.  I blame the RPGamer Extra Life stream as I ended up participating in it a bit immediately after this section.